# How to convert the new HTTP Client response body to String in Java 9?

Tags: java, java-9

As I was experimenting with new HTTP Client in Java 9:

```
HttpResponse response = HttpRequest
                .create(new URI("http://stackoverflow.com/"))
                .GET()
                .response();
```

The returned `HttpResponse` provides a `body` method which accepts an implementation of `BodyProcessor`. The `BodyProcessor` javadoc says:

> Implementations of this interface are provided in `HttpResponse` which
>   write responses to `String`, `byte[]`, `File`, `Consumer<byte[]>`. Custom
>   implementations can also be used.

But i couldn't find those implementations. How can I convert the response body to, say, `String`? Should I implement the `BodyProcessor` interface for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The javadoc correctly states that Implementations are available in `HttpResponse`

```
HttpResponse response = HttpRequest
                .create(new URI("http://stackoverflow.com/"))
                .GET()
                .response();

String body = response.body(HttpResponse.asString());
```

Comment: The reason that couldn't find those impls is that I was searching for those static methods in the `BodyProcessor` itself. Thanks for your answer anyway..